# how to get second row for each group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this 2 set of data with 2 different lat and long I want only second row for each lat,long 
eg. 18.08  and 72.5 I want  40
 and 20.18 abd 79.22 I want 21

following input is resultant output by other query please let me know how to achieve this

```
 depth   lat    long    
  35    18.08    72.5    
  40    18.08    72.5    --<-- 
  45    18.08    72.5    
  50    18.08    72.5    
  55    18.08    72.5    
  60    18.08    72.5    
  9      20.18   79.22   
  21     20.18   79.22   --<--
  46     20.18   79.22   
  57     20.18   79.22   
  73     20.18   79.22   
  74     20.18   79.22
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do this using window function `row_number`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over (
            partition by lat, long order by depth
            ) as rn
    from your_table t
    ) t
where rn = 2;
```

Comment: will long require with "  partition by lat "   eg   partition by lat,long

Comment: I think, it would be better to add row_number() over (partition by lat,long order by depth) as rn because there might be possibility of having same lat but different long. But in your case row_number will not change. Because of which there is a chance to get wrong result. Let me know your thoughts on that.